# Function is not defined with module.exports on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the error: *"login is not defined"* on my node.js app, when I try to get the function `login` in my `server.js` from a module `module1.js` which needs `data`:

```
//module1.js
module.exports = (data) => {
   var login = function(data){
      console.log(data)
   }
   exports.login = login;
};

//server.js
var test = require(__dirname + '/app/modules/module1.js')(data);
test.login();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When node starts executing module code, both `module.exports` and `exports` point to the same object. When you re-assign `module.exports`, you're specifying another object that will be returned from a module. In you case it's a function `(data)=>{...}`. The `exports` variable keeps pointing to the old module object.

You need the following:

```
module.exports = (data) => {
   var login = function(){
      console.log(data)
   }
   return {login: login};
};
```

Or this way shorter:

```
module.exports = (data) => {
   return {login: function(){
      console.log(data)
   }};
};
```

Or, if you want to export both functions, you need to add them to `exports` object.

Comment: @PierreNicolas, you're welcome. Don't forget you can accept my answer it it helped)